# Cursor Index Out Of Bounds while trying to get a value from the database

Tags: android, sql

im trying to make a method that return the value from the database and im getting CursorIndexOutOfBounds:
(The Line 94 is : String count = c.getString(1);)

```
public String getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_COUNT };

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=1",null, null, null, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String count = c.getString(1);
            return count;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

LogCat:

```
07-07 19:51:53.408: E/AndroidRuntime(27923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 19:51:53.408: E/AndroidRuntime(27923): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-07 19:51:53.408: E/AndroidRuntime(27923):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
07-07 19:51:53.408: E/AndroidRuntime(27923):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
07-07 19:51:53.408: E/AndroidRuntime(27923):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
07-07 19:51:53.408: E/AndroidRuntime(27923):    at com.example.fartsound.MyDataBase.getCount(MyDataBase.java:94)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `c.moveToFirst()` inside the if statement. if that returns false then the cursor is empty and would get that error

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
```

Comment: im getting null, what does that mean?(the method returns null)

Comment: because you return null which means your cursor is empty

Comment: which means the table is empty?

Comment: either that or nothing in your database supports that query

Answer (score 0):

cursor starts from '0' use this:

```
String count = c.getString(0);
```

Comment: tried it, still getting the same thing, besides, i want the value of the second columns

Answer (score 0):

The literature of moveToFirst() method:

> **public abstract boolean  moveToFirst ()**  Move the cursor to the first row.  This method will return false if the cursor is empty.
>
> **Returns** whether the move succeeded.

So your moveToFirst call is failing(because cusrsor has 0 elements) and that is the reason for crash.

Do this:

```
if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
      String count = c.getString(0);
      return count;
}
```